# Как повторять функцию через определенное время?

Tags: javascript

Есть запрос

```
function mass() {
    var req = getXmlHttp();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if(req.status == 200) {
                var AllPrivateMessages = req.responseText;
                document.getElementById('periubor').innerHTML = AllPrivateMessages;
                document.getElementById('periubor').innerHTML =  "dc` hf,jnjtn";
            }
            // тут можно добавить else с обработкой ошибок запроса
        }
    }
    req.open('GET', 'messages/privatemessageschat.php', true); 
    req.send(null);  // отослать запрос
}
```

Как повторять его через каждую секунду?

Comment: при вставке кода используйте кнопку "Отформатированный текст"

Comment: сори забыл

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[setInterval()](http://javascript.ru/setInterval)

Answer (score 3):

Почитайте [тут](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)
`setTimeout()` и `setInterval()`